# What sort of data structure or construct is "catch" in Try-Catch

Tags: c#

In the context of C#, one can have code as such:

```
try {
      ...
} 
catch {
      ... 
}
```

In other cases, the code can be:

```
try {
      ...
}
catch (Exception e) {
      ...
}
```

My question is: **What sort of data structure or construct is "catch"**? From the looks of the second example, it seems to be a method (in context of the C# programming language). But is it? If so, then why are the parentheses not required in the first example (since parenthesis are not optional for methods in C#)?

Comment: Just `catch` will catch ALL exceptions. The other specification will catch anything of type `Exception` (including sub-classes thereof). And no, it's not a function - it's a language construct.

Comment: I would say it's a clause.

Comment: The specification calls `try` a statement and `catch` a clause.

Comment: It is a clause like linuxrocks said which contains an Exception Data Structure.

Comment: @fredrik - with the exception (no pun intended..) of a StackOverflowException - at least not directly and if thrown via the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# has [Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/statement-keywords) (or statement keywords) which are nothing but program instructions.
Catch is a clause in C# try-catch statement (categorized in exception handling statements category). Also, since clauses are examined in order, you should catch more specific exceptions before the less specific ones.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

Answer (score 2):

`try-catch` is an example of what is called a **statement** in the context of the C# programming language, or other imperative programming languages. Statements are syntactic elements, part of how the language is constructed.

Have a look at the [documentation of try-catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) to see its definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try / Catch is a `statement`

> The try...catch statement is used to catch exceptions that occur
>   during execution of a block, and the try...finally statement is used
>   to specify finalization code that is always executed, whether an
>   exception occurred or not.

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/statements

Catch is a `clause` of the Try / Catch `statement`

> It is possible to use more than one specific catch clause in the same
>   try-catch statement.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch